# How to load particular page without JSP include prelude and coda

Tags: jsp, include

I have set up my web.xml file which loads footer and header but I want to separate my login page to load it without header footer. Does any know how can I achieve this.

Here is my Web.xml file configuration. I am using Netbeans

```xml
 <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>JSP configuration for the store front</description>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jspf/error/*</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>JSP configuration for the admin console</description>
        <url-pattern>/admin/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/login.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/error.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/admin/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/admin/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one new group without *include-prelude* and *include-coda*

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```