# Does the <jsp:include> tag apply <include-prelude> and <include-coda> configurations?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet that sets a request attribute named "snippet" and forwards to a JSP page.  The JSP page has a runtime include as follows:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/snippets/${snippet}.jsp/>
```

I also have the following  defined:

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/top.jsp</include-prelude>
    <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jsp/bottom.jsp</include-coda>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
</jsp-property-group>
```

I think what is happening is when the `<jsp:include>` triggers, the container also applies the `<include-prelude>` and `<include-coda>` configurations because I am seeing some wierd nested HTML code in my response.

Question is, is it possible `<include-prelude>` and `<include-coda>` is applied when using `<jsp:include>`?  If so, how can I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As given [How to load particular page without JSP include prelude and coda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610147/how-to-load-particular-page-without-jsp-include-prelude-and-coda), the answer seems to be to create a separate property group.

I suggest putting them in a sub-directory.

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>/includes/*</url-pattern>
</jsp-property-group>
```